# What is the right way to introspect a qooxdoo object?

Tags: qooxdoo

I want to list all members of a qooxdoo object. I found a way to do it, but I assume there must be a cleaner way?

```
for (var key in obj) {
  if (key.startsWith('$$user_')) {
    msg += 'name='+key.substring(7)+' = '+obj[key]+' [type='+typeof(obj[key])+']';
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you interested in the member functions or properties or what are you interested in exactly?

Comment: I am interested in the properties name and value

Answer (score 4):

Assuming it is properties you are interested in, you can use

```
var classProperties = qx.util.PropertyUtil.getAllProperties(obj.constructor);
for(var propertyName in classProperties) {
    ...
}
```

http://tinyurl.com/c4b2l5m

Comment: You can simply use the 'get' method [1] every object offers and access their values.

[1] http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/apiviewer/#qx.core.MProperty~get